# Codeigniter limit for pagination

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, pagination

I made this function in codeigniter:

```
public function get_users_pagination($q, $perpage, $pagenr, $type = 1)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('korisnici_tbl', array("type" => $type), $perpage,$pagenr);
    $this->db->like('email', $q);
    $this->db->or_like('name', $q);
    return $query->result();
}
```

But when the result is less than the $perpage variable it still returns rows in the amount of $perpage.

So if the $pagenr is for example 10 and there are 2 rows with type 1 it just returns 8 other rows of type 2 with it.

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` to check what is the query you are getting i guess there is a problem with `or_like`

Comment: It returns me this and looks alright to me:
SELECT * FROM (`korisnici_tbl`) WHERE `type` = 2 AND `email` LIKE '%%' OR `name` LIKE '%%' LIMIT 10

There are like 2 rows that are type 2 but it returns me 10 rows

Comment: this is because it fetches record where name matches or email matches you need wrap you or in a group like `type = 2 AND (email LIKE '%%' OR name LIKE '%%' )`

Comment: Yes I noticed that. When I remove the or_like it does work good. Any idea on how to do it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the ORs like this

```
$like = '(email LIKE \'%'.$q.'%\'';
$like .= ' OR name LIKE \'%'.$q.'%\')';
$this->db->where($like);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('korisnici_tbl', array("type" => $type));
$this->db->like('email', $q);
$this->db->or_like('name', $q);
$this->db->limit($pagination_start, $pagination_length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put on your model function:
$limit = 3; //maximum row's which you want to show in page's:

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. Clear answer will help people understand what you mean and will increase the chance of selecting as an answer